# asp.net timer not working

Tags: asp.net, timer

I am new to aspx and can not get my web timer to work. What am I missing here? Also DebugSet.logoutTime = 1800000 and DebugSet.logotWarnings = 3. The user is to be warned every minute before they are logged out of the system. These settings will be raised before the release, I just lowered them for testing purposes.

```
public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private LoggedUser _User;
    private Timer LogoutTimer;
    private int TmCnt = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _User = new LoggedUser(true);
        SetTimer();
    }
    private void SetTimer()
    {
        LogoutTimer = new Timer();
        LogoutTimer.Interval = DebugSet.logoutTime/DebugSet.logoutWarnings;
        LogoutTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(LogoutTimer_Tick);
        LogoutTimer.Enabled = true;
        LogoutTimer.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;
    }
    private void LogoutTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TmCnt++;
        if (TmCnt == DebugSet.logoutWarnings)
        {
            _User.UserLoggedIn = false;
            _User.SetSessions();
            LogoutTimer.Enabled = false;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["FCSWarning"] = "LoggedOut";
            Response.Redirect("../Views/index.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            int i = (DebugSet.logoutTime / (1000 * 60)) - ((DebugSet.logoutTime / (1000 * 60)) * TmCnt);
            string msg = "<Script language=javascript>alert('You will be logged out in " + i.ToString() + " min. due to inactivity.');</Script>";
            Response.Write(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a terrible idea. What if someone has your page open in two different tabs? Perhaps they don't mess with one of the tabs and they're working in the other. After the timeout, they'll be inexplicably logged out of your website for both tabs. Possibly causing a loss of data if they were filling out a form or had other unsaved changes. You really need to think about the implications.

Comment: My application will only allow them to be logged into one session. If they are already logged in then they will not be able to log in again

Comment: I didn't say they would be able to log in multiple times. It seems you're unfamiliar with the stateless nature of the web. Someone can open multiple tabs/windows to your website, even if they've only logged in once. And if you have this timeout logic like you've described in the question, it's going to result in a bad user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ASP.NET Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865.aspx) is an ASP.NET control. Each ASP.NET control must be added into a page control hierarchy, otherwise, it won't operate correctly or won't operate at all.

Add your Timer to page control hierarchy:

```
LogoutTimer = new Timer();
LogoutTimer.ID = "MyTimer";
this.Controls.Add(LogoutTimer);
LogoutTimer.Interval = DebugSet.logoutTime/DebugSet.logoutWarnings;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a winforms timer (I think). With websites all instances of variables and classes are destroyed when the page is send to the browser (garbage collection). So `LogoutTimer` only exists for a very short time. You need to use the Timer control.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx

You should know this also when working with websites, the Page Life Cycle:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx